# Open GL Adding rotation speed on objects

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

I am currently working on a mini project, trying to add some rotation speed on my objects, so that they can spin on themselves.
I tried the following but don't get it.

Here is the code snippet Im working on:

```
 ObjetDeJeu::ObjetDeJeu(glm::vec3 pPosition)
    : mPosition(pPosition), mOrientation(0,0,0), mSpeed()
{

}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
ObjetDeJeu::~ObjetDeJeu()
{

}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
void ObjetDeJeu::setVitesse(glm::vec2 pVitesse)
{
    mVitesse = pVitesse;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
void ObjetDeJeu::addSpeed(glm::vec2 pSpeedToAdd)
{
    mVitesse += pVitesseToAdd;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
glm::vec3 ObjetDeJeu::getPosition_ParentSpace()
{
    return mPosition;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
glm::vec3 ObjetDeJeu::getOrientation_ParentSpace()
{
    return mOrientation;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
void ObjetDeJeu::setPosition_ParentSpace(glm::vec3 pPosition)
{
    mPosition = pPosition;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
void ObjetDeJeu::setOrientation_ParentSpace(glm::vec3 pOrientation)
{
    mOrientation = pOrientation;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
void ObjetDeJeu::rotateZ(float angleDegree)
{
    mOrientation.z += angleDegree;
    if( mOrientation.z >= 180.0f ) 
    {
        mOrientation.z -= 360.0f;
    }
    if( mOrientation.z < -180.0f ) 
    {
        mOrientation.z += 360.0f;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
glm::mat4x4 ObjetDeJeu::getTransform_ParentSpace()
{
    glm::mat4x4 lTransfo;
    lTransfo = glm::translate( lTransfo , mPosition);
    lTransfo = glm::rotate(lTransfo, mOrientation.z, glm::vec3(0,0,1)); 
    lTransfo = glm::rotate(lTransfo, mOrientation.y, glm::vec3(0,1,0));
    lTransfo = glm::rotate(lTransfo, mOrientation.x, glm::vec3(1,0,0));
    return lTransfo;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
bool ObjetDeJeu::touche(ObjetDeJeu* obj)
{
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
void ObjetDeJeu::deplace(float dt)
{
    // vitesse * temps ecoule == deplacement.
    glm::vec3 deplacement = glm::vec3(mSpeed*dt, 0); 

    mPosition += deplacement;

}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
void ObjetDeJeu::dessiner()
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  

        glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.5,1.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);

    glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the orientation vector as a set of axis-aligned rotations. This is probably not what you want.

You can manage rotations as a local coordinate system matrix that you apply as a single transform:

```
M = [a d g 0]
    [b e h 0]
    [c f i 0]
    [0 0 0 1]
```

Where the vectors [a b c], [d e f] and [g h i] represent the x-, y- and z-axis of the rotated local coordinate system. When you want to apply a rotation, firstly, it should expressed as an angle around a nominated axis (or a quaternion, but let's not get ahead of ourselves). You compute the transform matrix for this rotation and apply it to each of the axis vectors in M. Then, at rendering time, you apply M as the right-most transform before rendering the object.